# How to apply filter on Many to many field without using for loop

Tags: python, django, filter, many-to-many

I Model is like

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

class Intership(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    intership = models.ManyToManyField(Intership,null= True, blank=True)
```

I am looking forward to get all the student who done internship in a company with name "xyz".

i have the code

```
company_name = "xyz"
stds
for student in students:
    interships = student.intership.all()
    for intership in interships:
        if intership.company.name == company_name:
            stds.append(student)
```

Is it possible to get it all this on a single query??

Comment: `Student.objects.filter(intership__company__name =company_name  )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just filter on the `Student`s itself:

```
Student.objects.filter(intership__company__name='xyz')
```

You might want to use `.distinct()` here, since otherwise a `Student` that multiple internships in the same company will be listed multiple times:

```
Student.objects.filter(intership__company__name='xyz').distinct()
```

> **Note**: It is `internship`, not <s>`intership`</s>.

Comment: [Here's the reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

`Mymodel.objects.filter(username='abcd')` will give list of match record

`Mymodel.objects.get(pk='abcd')` will return single record with matching on primary key value